# Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 or Xamarin.Android.Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android application that is being built through a build server. The application is targeting API Level 23 and Min Android Version 4.1 (API 16). During debug the application works fine, but when the build server compiles the application, packages it, signs, and aligns it, it crashes on load with the error:

> Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 or Xamarin.Android.Platform

Most phones result in an immediate crash with the error mentioned above, but a handful of devices work fine. The only thing those devices have in common is they were used to deploy the application during development. This leads me to believe they have the shared run time installed and hence why it doesn't fail. The build server has the latest Xamarin.Android (just like the dev machines), latest Java, latest JDK, and latest Android libraries (per the SDK Manager). The configuration being built doesn't use the shared runtime, it is not linking (although I also tried it with linking SDK assemblies only), and it only supports `armeabi-7va` ABI.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe my problem was that I was using a shared run time (Had copied a release configuration but that didn't get moved). Great clue with the app only working on debugged devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the problem which seems to be a bug with Xamarin (or Mono?). We have AndroidManifest.xml and AndroidManifestAlpha.xml. During the build we specify `/p:AndroidManifest=Properties/AndroidManifestAlpha.xml` to the MSBUILD arguments, but the compilation adds all the activity, services, and mono information to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file only. The build eventually uses the specified `AndroidManifestAlpha.xml` file and compiles the APK without the mono runtime; resulting in the error mentioned above.

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov yes. My build process modifies the manifest file with a script

Answer (score 0):

Change the Target Android version. In VisualStudio on Mac, the path is Project->.Options->General->TargetFramework.

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds this error check my answer in another post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678522/1106547

It's for Xamarin Studio, but I guess should work for VS Xamarin extension too.

The main idea in my case was to put **android-25** (or **android-23** for the case of the original question) folder to the Android SDK **platforms** directory.

I suppose it allowed the Xamarin engine to install correct **"..Platform.ApiLevel_"** APK and use the shared library.