# Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I get that exception in my Xamarin.Forms Android App (all latest SDK) on a Samsung Galaxy mobile phone on app launch.

> 2-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.rolsped.stage.TruckerApp, PID: 29826 02-15 01:49:56.431 29826
>   29826 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get
>   provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
>   to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or
>   Xamarin.Android.Platform! 02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E
>   AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6770)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6362)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6302)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222) 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826
>   E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 02-15 01:49:56.431
>   29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application
>   Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform! 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38) 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6767)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 10 more
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   Xamarin.Android.Platform 02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E
>   AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:368)
>   02-15 01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32) 02-15
>   01:49:56.431 29826 29826 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 11 more

I get it only on that type of a mobile phone. 
All I found until now doesn't solve that issue including setting the `AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk` to `false` what I found [here](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.co.at/2016/11/how-to-fix-xamarin-android-app.html).

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks

Eric

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Disabling `Use Shared Runtime` from Project ->Options->Android Options
solved it.

Comment: This should be marked best answer, even if you don't want to toot your own horn. It's the correct fix.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as mentioned in the answer above:

```
Disabling Use Shared Runtime from Project -> Options -> Android Options
```

should work in most cases, and that is indeed the first thing to try. But if that doesn't work, you may also try to add to the list of *supported architectures* from **Android Project Properties -> Advanced** as shown in the images below.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/152808/#Comment_152808) out, this might help you. Looks like they had the same problem before. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and didn't solve the issue. I posted the answer what I found here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83266/unable-to-find-application-mono-android-platform-apilevel-24-or-xamarin-android-platform

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned **Use Shared Runtime** option disabling is definitely the solution to allow app deployment. Though that option should allow faster deployments during the development.

There should be a way to use the Shared Runtime and run apps successfuly.

In my case I deployed a fresh app with `minSdk=16` on a device with **API 19**.
So I found "**Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_19-1.apk**" in the `/data/app/` folder.

The compiler Android platform was of API 28.
But the exception says:

> Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_25 or Xamarin.Android.Platform

So it's a complete mess.
Maybe on a device with API 25 it would work.

---

**Edit**:

Finally, what worked for me.
Downloaded **"platform-25_r03.zip"** from Android SDK, unpacked it to **"platforms"** folder, renamed to "android-25". Then created new project, Run.

(Oh, and previously removed Mono apps):

```
adb uninstall Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
adb uninstall Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_19
```

It installed **"Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_25.apk"**.

Dev parameters for this case:

- Xamarin Studio 6.3
- Xamarin.Android 7.3.1.2
- JDK 8

And in the Xamarin Studio -> Help -> About it says:

> Supported Android versions:
>   4.1 (API level 16)
>   4.4 (API level 19)
>   7.1 (API level 25)

After adding API 25 platform folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue from a build in Azure DevOps but not locally, it wasn't picking up the fact I had set this in the project.

I had to manually set `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk` and `AndroidUseSharedRuntime` in the Android build step, this is the yaml:

```
  - task: XamarinAndroid@1
    displayName: 'Build Android App'
    inputs:
      projectFile: '$(AndroidProject)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      outputDirectory: '$(OutputDirectory)'
      msbuildArchitectureOption: x64
      msbuildArguments: '/verbosity:detailed /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true" /p:EmbedAssembliesIntoApk="true" /p:AndroidUseSharedRuntime="false"'
```